# Loop through html elements and check if the text contains a specific word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to loop through a list of html elements and log to the console only the ones which contain a specific word.

```js
const li = $('ul li');
for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  //If any of the li's  match with a specific word. 'Item A' for example then log it to the console.
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Item A</li>
    <li>Item B</li>
    <li>Item C</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use jQuery `:contains` selector:

```js
$('ul li:contains(A)').each((_,el) => console.log(el.id))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li id="li-A">Item A</li>
    <li id="li-B">Item B</li>
    <li id="li-C">Item C</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `$.each()` for this one

```js
$.each($('ul li'), function(){
 if($(this).text().toLowerCase() === "item a"){
     console.log($(this).text())
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Item A</li>
    <li>Item B</li>
    <li>Item C</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const li = $('ul li');
for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  if(li[i].innerText === 'Desired String') {
  //do something
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A library like jquery is not necessary for this simple task. You can use a filter for filtering and you can use match for your regular expression. With es6 you get concise syntax, and with vanilla you get performance. Everything else is an abstraction.

```js
let elements = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].children;
let arr = Array.from(elements, node => node.innerText);
arr = arr.filter(items => items.match('A'));
console.log(...arr);
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Item A</li>
    <li>Item B</li>
    <li>Item C</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```